# Error While uploading to windows Azure using powershell Script

Tags: asp.net, powershell, azure-deployment

I am uploading the application to windows Azure using the powershell Script

```
    New-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $servicename -Label MySite 
          -Slot "Staging" -Package "C:\Users\ronak\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\samplewebrole\samplewebrole\bin\Release\app.publish\samplewebrole.cspkg" 
          -Configuration "C:\Users\ronak\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\samplewebrole\samplewebrole\bin\Release\app.publish\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg"
```

When I run this I receive an error as follows

```
New-AzureDeployment : Unable to write data to the transport connection: An
    existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    At line:14 char:1
    + New-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $servicename -Label MySite -Slot "Staging" -Pac...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureDeployment], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.NewAzureDeploymentCommand
```

To resolve this i found some suggestion to increase the size the asp.net can upload. Is there any other reason this is happening?

Also I am able to create cloud service and storage but cant upload my package to it.

Answer (score 1):

I moved my script to the virtual machine which is hosted on azure and this error is no more so i think this error was due to my firewall or due to the slow internet connection.the script is running as desired on the virtual machine and i am able to automate my deployment process.

Comment: "due to the slow internet connection" - this helped my issue.